# How to make appendix appear in part level of table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

In a `book` documentclass I would like to have an appendix which appears in the table of contents at the part level. The TOC should look like this:

```
Preface
Part title
  Chapter title
  Chapter title
Part title
  Chapter title
  Chapter title
Appendix: Some title
Bibliography
Index
```

I know how to include the bibliography and the index with `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{...}` and I even know about `\phantomsection` trick to get it to point to the right place in the PDF.

But how do I convince the appendix to go to the `part` level of TOC? It goes under `chapter` of the last part.

I do not care if I make an appendix "by hand", i.e., without using \appendix.
By the way, I am using `\titlesec` to customize chapter and part formatting.

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you currently have an appendix (or several appendixes) that are treated as "chapters", and you want to insert an entry in the ToC that says "Appendix" (or "Appendixes") ahead of the appendix-related entries in the ToC? If that's the case, have you considered issuing the command `\part*{Appendix}` ahead of the appendix material? Please advise.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: There is a single appendix, but I would like it to appear in the `part` part of toc. I am currently using `\appendix` followed by `chapter`, but I don't care about what I use. I would just like the appendix not to be included in "Part 2" of the book (like bibliography, which I included in the toc by hand so I could control where in the toc appears, but appendix puts itself in the toc).

Comment: `\part*{Appendix}` is not good because it creates a whole page saying just "Appendix". I want the appendix to look like a chapter, not a part, but it should appear in the TOC at the part level.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have only one appendix, a "one shot hack" should be sufficient:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\appchapter}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \patchcmd{\@chapter}
   {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}}
   {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}}
   {}{}
  \patchcmd{\@chapter}
   {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}}
   {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}}
   {}{}
  \chapter{#1}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Preface}

\part{Part title}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\chapter{Chapter title}

\part{Part title}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\chapter{Chapter title}

\backmatter
\appendix
\appchapter{Appendix: Some title}

\chapter{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! One more detail: I use `hyperref` to generate the table of contents in the PDF file. That is still showing up under chapter. Also, how would I just prevent `\appchapter` from putting anything at all into TOC? (Then I can put it in by hand.)