# Issue with Hyperlinks in PDF using Hyperref Package

Tags: hyperref, pdf, grouping

I am currently facing an issue with the placement of hyperlinks in a PDF document that I am typesetting using `LaTeX` and the `hyperref` package. I have tried various approaches, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired result.

My document is structured into parts and chapters, with appendices and an analytical index. The problem I am encountering is related to the arrangement of hyperlinks in the generated PDF.

The structure I am aiming for is as follows:

Book:

- Part 1

  - Chapter 1 of Part 1
  - Chapter 2 of Part 1
  - Chapter 3 of Part 1
- Part 2

  - Chapter 1 of Part 2
  - Chapter 2 of Part 2
  - Chapter 3 of Part 2
- Appendix 1
- Appendix 2
- Analytical Index

However, the hyperlinks in the PDF are being grouped incorrectly, and the arrangement appears as follows:

Book:

- Part 1

  - Chapter 1 of Part 1
  - Chapter 2 of Part 1
  - Chapter 3 of Part 1
- Part 2

  - Chapter 1 of Part 2
  - Chapter 2 of Part 2
  - Chapter 3 of Part 2
  - Appendix 1
  - Appendix 2
  - Analytical Index

I have tried using `\phantomsection` before `\addcontentsline` for both the appendices and the analytical index, but the issue persists.

My `hyperref` setup is as follows:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{bookmarksnumbered}

\hypersetup{hidelinks}

\hypersetup{pdfauthor={My Name}, pdftitle={My Title}}
```

If you need more information about my `LaTeX` code or setup, please let me know.

EDIT: following my example as suggested (I'm sorry if I reply only now, I was in holiday for a while)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt,italian,notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage[UTF8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.1.}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./files/}}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{imakeidx} %indice analitico
\makeindex
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[maxdepth=6]{gitinfo2}
\captionsetup{tableposition=top,figureposition=bottom,font=small}
\captionsetup{format=hang,labelfont={bf}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
%============= LISTINGS ======================
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{mGreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mGray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mPurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backgroundColour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\definecolor{backgroundColourC++}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{C}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backgroundColour},   
    commentstyle=\color{mGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{mGray},
    stringstyle=\color{mPurple},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
%   breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
%   numbers=left,                    
%   numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    language=C
}
\lstdefinestyle{C++}{
    language=C++,
    backgroundcolor=\color{backgroundColourC++},   
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
    morecomment=[l][\color{magenta}]{\#},
    captionpos=b,
    showspaces=false,
    keepspaces=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    breaklines=true
}
\lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible}
\addto\captionsitalian{\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Codice}}
\addto\captionsitalian{\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Elenco dei listati}}

%==============FANCY==============
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\fontsize{10}{12} C e C++}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{}
\cfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\fontsize{10}{12} \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
%=================================

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarksnumbered,
    bookmarksopen=false,
    hidelinks,
    hypertexnames=false,
    pdfauthor={Micky Mouse}, 
    pdftitle={My title}
}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\makeindex[columns=2, title=Indice analitico]

\usepackage{bookmark}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\author{Micky Mouse}
\title{My Title }
\date{MyDate}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\maketitle
\begin{center}
    
    Rev.~\gitCommitterIsoDate\\
    
    Hash:~\gitHash\\
    
\end{center}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings
\newpage

\section*{Premessa}
Some text as introduction of the book

\pagestyle{fancy}
\part{First part}
\include{A}
\include{B}

\part{Second part}
\include{C}
\include{D}

\appendix
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\include{Apendix 1}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\indexname}
\printindex
\cleardoublepage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108467/47927

Comment: you are speaking about the bookmarks, not the hyperlinks. And you should make a small but complete example. That makes it much easier to test and provide a solution.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 0):

Add `\bookmarksetup{startatroot}` (from the `bookmark` package) to end a part before a new chapter (or appendix).